# Code Freezes Half Way Through - PHP

Tags: php

I have this relatively complex combinations and permutations code that I have to execute in CLI. The code takes a number as command line parameter and then outputs a list of all permutations of all unique combinations. The arrays are strings of numbers separated by a space.

The code works nice if N is 6 or less. Even 7. However when I pass n=8 the code simply freezes,, it stops and doesn't move on.

How can I fix this so that N can be 8.

N will never be larger than 8, BUT the code must be able to execute with 8.

Here is the code

```
    for ($i=0; count($list) < $nop; $i++) {
        shuffle($array);
        $tmp = implode(' ', $array);
            if (!isset($list[$tmp])) {
                $list[$tmp] = 1;
    }}
```

Thanks for all advice in advance.

Comment: You have used same variable in inner & outer loop in function ccmbo.

Comment: @Harry, first one i, the second j.

Comment: @sachleen sorry my mistake i have seen two j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i=0; count($list) < $nop; $i++) {
```

causes an infinite loop. Nowhere in the loop does the size of `$list` or `$nop` change so if `count($list) < $nop` is true, it'll be an infinite loop.

Comment: Dude, I cancelled my answer. You said the same thing! @sachleen `:D`

Comment: if you execute the script (the script I posted is whole,, just create a php file and execute in CLI by passing n) you will see what I mean. if n is 6 for example,, it works great..

Comment: That is why you have to appreciate FRESH set of eyes :)) Thanks so much! The line that says "for ($i=0; count($list) < $nop; $i++)" is indeed an impossible line,, lol. it should say "for ($i=0; $i < $nop; $i++)" ...